# Multiple domain Google Analytics tracking under one account while excluding one domain?

Tags: google-analytics

Here's the problem I am having:

Currently, we need to track across www.chess.com and secure.chess.com.
However, I cannot set the domain to .chess.com because the cookie causes some problems on another domain, live.chess.com.

So, to work around this, in code - I do something like this:

```
<? if (HTTPS) { ?>
    <script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-01']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'secure.chess.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    </script>
<? } else { ?>
    <script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-02']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.chess.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    </script>
<? } ?>
```

However, this forces us to maintain 2 analytics accounts (UA-XXXXX-01 and UA-XXXXX-02) and creates a separation between HTTPS and HTTP traffic.

How can I set this up so that ONE analytics account will track both secure.chess.com and www.chess.com without setting a top level cookie (.chess.com)?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/google-analytics-multiple-domains-under-one-account-while-excluding-one-domain).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copied from [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/google-analytics-multiple-domains-under-one-account-while-excluding-one-domain/5120#5120):

---

```
<? if ( %%HTTP_HOST%% != 'live.chess.com' ) { ?>
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-01']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '<? echo %%HTTP_HOST%% ?>']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
<? } ?>
```

(Where `%%HTTP_HOST%%` is a variable generated by your server-side script)

**Edit:** To confirm, the following code is included on all pages generated at secure.chess.com and www.chess.com and no script errors display at secure.chess.com correct?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:'   == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'   : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```